# NTP time check error after DST time change

Tags: java, apache-commons, dst, ntp

I want to check the time shift of the system clock. This is my code:

```
NTPUDPClient client = new NTPUDPClient();
client.setDefaultTimeout(5000);
client.open();
TimeInfo info = client.getTime(InetAddress.getByName("ntp1.inrim.it"));
info.computeDetails();
long offset=info.getOffset()==null?0:info.getOffset();
```

The NTPClient class is coming from **org.apache.commons.net.ntp** package.

The problem is that in a particular server with Windows 2008 I got **3600** as timeshift and the problem is happening just after the DaySaving time change of last Sunday night.
I checked windows setup and time seems to be right, timezone is correct and also daylight setting is on.

Do you think this is a Windows problem or may I check some NTP java client configutation?

Comment: How recently has your Java installation been updated?  Java maintains the timezone information within Java - it doesn't use the O/S timezones.

Comment: It is Java v. 1.8 updated at settember. How can Java knows where my installation to choose the right timezone?

Answer (score 0):

NTP only transmits UTC-based timestamps.  Any alignment to time zone (including DST) is done purely *after* receiving the UTC time from the source.

[`TimeInfo.getOffset()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/TimeInfo.html#getOffset()) returns the offset needed to adjust the clocks - the difference between the remote-computer's UTC time and the local computer's UTC time.  It says nothing at all about time zones or DST.

That said, if indeed it is shifting by an hour, then it's possible that either you or the remote computer are converting from UTC to local time or vice/versa incorrectly.  Since you said it's Windows, you should make sure you have selected the appropriate local time zone in the Windows date/time control panel settings, and that you have **not** unchecked "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time".

Of course, it's also entirely possible that the source clock is simply set incorrectly.  However, that usually only happens if someone sets the clock manually. Most NTP servers take their time from some other higher-stratum NTP server, so this is less likely.